# What to do if I am unable to present at airport if I booked ticket online with my credit card for a friend at Qatar airways?

Tags: bookings, qatar-airways

I have booked a ticket for my foreigner friend for Qatar airways flight. Flight is now day after tomorrow. But now that I saw Qatar airways say that I need to be present at airport at the time of departure. This is impossible for me. Which documents required to submit and who to contact regarding this?

Comment: You should contact Qatar Airways customer services in your country.

Comment: You may be able to go to a Qatar Airways ticket office and present your card in person there, removing the requirement to be present when your friend checks in.  I have a friend who had to do the same with a different airline when he bought a ticket for his (adult) son.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the more annoying airline rules and it's mostly about fraud prevention and not any specific legal requirements. Hence, you may be able to talk your way out of it but you probably need to improvise and sweet talk a bit. Here are some ideas:

1. Call Qatar RIGHT NOW and ask them what to do
2. Make a photo of your credit card (both sides) and sent the pictures to your friend
3. Make sure both you and your friend both have online accounts and try to associate with the online account using the booking reference. Turns out, Lufthansa waives the "present credit card" rule, if you have an online account with them
4. Make sure that your friend has all documents regarding the booking: receipt, confirmation, etc.
5. Create a "letter of booking intent", where you inform the airline that you have indeed booked this ticket for your friend with your credit card, that he doesn't have physical access to this credit card and that you are willing to confirm this in whatever way the airline sees fit. Add you contact info.
6. Make sure you and your friend can communicate during check in, i.e. cell phones charged and on proper access plans, be available during that time, etc.

The key here is that you or your friend need to convince the check in agent that the booking is real and not fraudulent. The agent (or supervisor) has the ability to waive the requirement, you just need to convince them to do so.

Comment: (+1) Lots of useful ideas, maybe worth adding the suggestion @phoog in a comment, namely presenting yourself to a ticket office with the card?

Comment: I would like to ask what would happen if his friend checking in online rather than at the airport?